# access multiple array using angular

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to access multiple array from json. Based on the modification I have to show tick mark.

With my current code the tick mark is coming for only one modified row it's not working for multiple scenario.

```
this.edited = params.Details[0].countryName;

 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.countryName}}
     <i *ngIf="(element.countryName == edited )" class="text-success fa fa-check-circle"></i>  
 </td>
```

With above ts code the tick mark is coming for only one country though user enter value for multiple countries still the tick mark  is showing for **0** row

console.log

```
0:{value: "7",countryCode: "AUS  ",countryName: "AUSTRALIA"}
1:{value: "6",countryCode: "IND  ",countryName: "INDIA"}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you create a Stckblitz or show more code. https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

Add an edited key on the object.

```
0:{value: "7",countryCode: "AUS  ",countryName: "AUSTRALIA","edited":false}
1:{value: "6",countryCode: "IND  ",countryName: "INDIA","edited":false}
```

so when ever you toggle the `td` the `edited` key will be changed.
Make the change on the template.

```
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.countryName}}
   <i *ngIf="element.edited" class="text-success fa fa-check-circle"></i>  
 </td>
```

Not sure how you are going to toggle the change but you can consider

```
(click) ="element.edited=!element.edited"
```